# .Net form focus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus

I Have a .net form with multiple controls in it.. Textbox , labels ... When the form is shown on screen the textbox get the focus by default. When i try to scroll the form using mouse scroll wheel  the scroll messages are basically going to Textbox and hence the form is not getting scrolled..

I tried setting

```
textbox.capture = false
form.capture = true; 
form.focus();
```

But nothing seems to get the attention away from the textbox. Any clue as how to force the form to get the mouse events rather that it's controls??

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) for `Control.Focus()` states:

> [...]
>
> A control can be selected and receive
>   input focus if all the following are
>   true: the Selectable value of
>   ControlStyles is set to true, it is
>   contained in another control, and all
>   its parent controls are both visible
>   and enabled.
>
> The Windows Forms controls in the
>   following list are not selectable.
>   Controls derived from these controls
>   are also not selectable.
>
> - Panel
> - GroupBox
> - PictureBox
> - ProgressBar
> - Splitter
> - Label
> - LinkLabel (when there is no link present in the control)
>
> ---
>
> ### *NoteNote:*
>
> ***`Focus`*** is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors.
>   Instead, application programmers should use the **`Select`** method or the
>   **`ActiveControl`** property for child controls, or the **`Activate`** method for forms.
>
> ---

Comment: But, from the same docs: "The control can have the input focus while not displaying any visual cues of having the focus. This behavior is primarily observed by the nonselectable controls listed below, or any controls derived from them."